# how can I resize the viewport centering the image without stretch it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Here's my actual object:

[image]

It's 100x92,071px. I'd like to select (and export) a 100x100px box/viewport, with the image centered horizontally/vertically. i.e. increase the canvas, keeping  my object centered (and not stretched).

How can I do it? I'm using Illustrator 23.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways I can think of

1. Resize the artboard and centre your image on it. When outputting use *File > Save As*, and check the "Use artboards" option.

[image]

**OR**

2. Add a 100x100 box with no fill or stroke around your artwork, select all and group. Use *File > Export Selection*.

[image]

Comment: I like the first option. Once I've resized the Artboard, what's the correct way to align horizontal/vertical? let say I place 100x100 (i.e. a bit of margin), how than center the selected object? Can you edit question show to me also this?

Comment: @markzzz I just used snapping to align them, you could use the alignment panel though. My answer isn't a tutorial. We don't really do full step by tutorials here. We assume users already have some basic understanding of the application. If you are looking for detailed step by step tutorials, there are lots on youtube.